# extension library and non english characters

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Is there any problem with extension library 8.5.3.20111208.0717, specifically dialog component, and non english characters. I have an empty dialog and when I add its title, if the title is in English there is no problem, but if it is in Greek the xpage doesn't open in Designer and the following exception occurs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editpart.XFacesEditPartFactory.createEditPart(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.createChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editpart.CustomRenderingElementEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.DocumentEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.SimpleRootEditPart.setContents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.viewer.XMLGraphicalViewerImpl.setContents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editor.AbstractXMLVisualEditor.initializeGraphicalViewer(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editor.XFacesEditor.initializeGraphicalViewer(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editor.AbstractXMLVisualEditor.createGraphicalViewer(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditor.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editor.AbstractXMLVisualEditor.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editor.XVEMultiPageEditor.createPages(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editor.XFacesMultiPageEditor.createPages(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.dialog.DesignElementUtil.openEditorWithImplicitLock(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.dialog.DesignElementUtil.openEditorWithImplicitLock(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.dialog.DesignElementUtil.openDesignElement(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.dialog.DesignElementUtil.openDesignElement(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.navigator.designtimemodelcontroller.DesignTimeModelWebPages.openDesignElement(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.navigator.ComponentBookmark.openDesign(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.navigator.ComponentBookmark.openDesign(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.navigator.ComponentBookmark$8.doubleClick(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.internal.RCPApplication.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.startLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone knows the reason about this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a known problem (SPR #VNTR9234WA).

It happens with several components (especially components that shows label on the design window) and with non-english languages.

It has been fixed after Domino Designer 8.5.3FP3 and a more recent version of Extension Library. I don't remember the exact version for the Extension Library, but I guess it was around 2012 December version.

For corrupted XPages or Custom Controls, you will not be able to open within DDE. You can, however use XML editor (via right click) to fix them.

Comment: Thank you Serdar! It has been driving me crazy for a whole day to find what the problem was. Yes, it's true that a later version of extension library fixes this situation, as the xpage that I am working on was created by a colleaugue that has a newer version and didn't face any problems. The thing is that in production server we use the standard version that comes with the upgrade pack of Designer. I guess we can't do a lot about it...

Comment: The problem exists on both extlib and designer code. Both should be upgraded and unfortunately, upgrade pack has the faulty code :(

Comment: Can you please tell me how to find the issue "SPR #VNTR9234WA" ? I googled it but no results were returned. Do you know the page where they are defined?

Comment: It's an internal SPR which we cannot see. It is possibly the same problem with SPR #GGRD8QTT5B which has been fixed in 8.5.3 FP3...

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/5c087391999d06e7852569280062619d/cc7afff7f99aa40285257ac60063305e?OpenDocument